# Support and irreducible components of a divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Given an algebraic variety $X$ of dimension $n$ (over, say, $\mathbb{C}$), a divisor $D$ of $X$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination
$$D = \sum a_iD_i$$
of codimension one subvarieties $D_i$ of $X$. The support $\mathrm{Supp}(D)$ of $D$ is the set $\{D_i:a_i \neq 0\}$. Since $D$ is a variety, it makes sense to talk about its irreducible components.

**Question.** What does this statement mean: For a point $P \in \mathrm{Supp}(D)$, we consider the irreducible components $E$ of $D$ passing through $P$.

Does anyone have an explicit example illustrating how an irreducible component of a divisor $D$ can pass through a point in the support of $D$?

For a curve, a divisor $D$ is a linear combination of points $\sum_{i=1}^na_iP_i, a_i \neq 0$. The irreducible components of $D$ would have to be the points $P_i$ themselves. Here it seems to me that $P_i$ would pass through $P_j$ if and only if $i = j$. Are the higher dimensions any different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The support $\operatorname{Supp}(D)$ of $D$ is the set $\{D_i:a_i \neq 0\}$.

I can't tell  if you are being sloppy or have conceptual misunderstanding, but this is not correct. The support is $$\operatorname{Supp} D = \bigcup_{i:a_i \neq 0} D_i,$$ which is a subset of $X$. What you wrote is a finite subset of the power set of $X$.

Now the irreducible components of $\operatorname{Supp} D$ are exactly the $D_i$ with $a_i \neq 0$, because they are irreducible by definition (as they are varieties).

Your picture for curves seems mostly correct to me.

> Are the higher dimensions any different?

Indeed. Say $X = \mathbb C^2$ is the affine plane, and consider the two coordinate axes $L_1 = \{\, x = 0 \,\}$ and $L_2 = \{\, y = 0 \,\}$. The support of the divisor $D = L_1 - L_2$ is the union of the axes, i.e.
$$\operatorname{Supp} D = \{\, x\cdot y = 0 \,\} = L_1 \cup L_2.$$
Now the point $P = (0,0)$, is contained in both irreducible components of $\operatorname{Supp} D$, but $Q = (1,0)$  is only contained  in $L_2$.

Comment: Indeed I got the support horribly wrong. Nice example, that was very clear, thanks.